# Quantum fluctuations in a classical domain?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-information, decoherence, fluctuation-dissipation

"In the presence of chaos, even small ﬂuctuations
(including quantum ﬂuctuations) can be ampliﬁed to produce large uncertainties in later
behavior"(https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9210010)

Is there some experimental evidence for the amplification of the quantum fluctuations in a classic domain (typically m, s, kg)?

Comment: You may want to check Casimir effect. It is not strictly amplification, but it shows macroscopic effect of vacuum fluctuations.

Comment: I already know about this effect. By the word "quantum fluctuation" I mean any off-diagonal phenomena (i.e. non-compatible observables).

Answer (score -3):

There was an interesting example of "macroscopic QM" shown in a recent show of "Through the Wormhole." I can't remember the material used, I think it was silicon. Liquid silicon was put in a dish, and then vibrated very quickly. The surface had a very rapid vibration which was controlled very accurately. Then a certain sized (totally macroscopic) droplet of silicon was very gently placed (dropped) onto the surface, and it then started bouncing up and down. This set up "long" waves in the liquid silicon surface, larger than the small surface "jitter." These "long" waves propagated around the dish, bouncing off its edges and superpositioning with its reflections, etc. This experiment produced "macroscopic" versions of de Broglie "matter-waves." A lot of scientists said "so what." But it did show something interesting, to me. A double slit was placed in the dish, and bouncing droplets with their "dragged along matter-waves" sent through the slits. You could see all this without any "microscopes." Even a single droplet, when passing through just one of the slits, did not exit "continoulsy," in the sense of exit direction. When the macroscopic liquid silicon waves were "squished through" a macroscopic slit, the silicon droplet "riding along" (which was smaller than a slit) exited with only certain, quantized directions. Once again though, a lot of scientists said so what, all of this can be modeled very accurately using classical physics, even the "squishing in" of a wave passing through a slit, forcing the quantization on exit. But this to me is similar to how electrons "exit" crystals in electron diffraction experiments. In these experiments, the "silicon droplet" is the electron, which is shot through a crystal (the slits), and if only certain exit locations and directions are produced (forced) during the electron’s passage through the crystal, the electron should only be "spit out" of the crystal in certain directions. This could explain the diffraction pattern produced.

In the silicon experiment, I am sure forces, etc., were measured, and certainly the scientists could have used the mks system for measuring.